Can any person be a Holy Spirit?
Can a Buddhist monk or a yogi be a Holy Spirit?
As far as I understand, they're masters in doing deep breathing and meditation.
For me, there are only a few monks/nuns who have mastered the technique above. Unfortunately, I cannot find any Christians, pastors, or priests who know anything about it, but normally they will respond by citing Sola Fide (faith alone) or with the advice to just pray everyday so eventually the skill will be awakened by itself. Not even psychologists, psychiatrists, or regular medical doctors know about it, or they only have very basic knowledge.
A few high level monks I did find meet all 11 personal characteristics of the Holy Spirit listed in this article, placing a nice bow on this topic:

He’s referred to as a Person (John 6:63; 14:26; Rom. 8:11, 16, 26; 1 John 5:6).

He speaks (2 Sam. 23:2; Acts 1:16; 8:29; 10:19; 11:12; 13:2; 21:11; 28:25–26; 1 Tim. 4:1; Heb. 3:7–8; Rev. 2:7; 14:13; 22:17).

He witnesses (John 15:26).

He searches (1 Cor. 2:11).

He can be grieved (Isa. 63:10; Eph. 4:30).

He loves (Rom. 15:30).

He has a mind (Rom. 8:27).

He has intelligence (1 Cor. 2:10–11).

He can be tested (Acts 5:9).

He can be resisted (Acts 7:5).

He has a will (1 Cor. 2:11; 12:7–11).


Can I get their advice and learn their technique of deep breathing and meditation, providing I do them under the conditions below?

The technique is not related to religion but rather to science or logic.

I am not required to worship any form of Idol or Gods (only the Mahayana version of Buddhism may have a theology of worship, but the original Shakyamuni, the founder of Buddhism, didn't mention anything about worshiping).

I am not being invited or forced into Buddhism.


They also don't try to convert me, but instead:

They praise and respect Christianity.

They wish me well in Christianity and allow me to share the Gospel in the Monastery.

They offer help whenever there is a need, such as co-operating in doing charity work.

Buddhism members are willing to join my cell group to learn about or even to one day (soon?) join Christianity.

Buddhism members are willing to cooperate in a mission filled with Sharing the Gospel activities when my church needs additional man-power.



how does deep breathing and meditation equate to one being a/the Holy Spirit? Is this a claim by Buddhist monks? I don't believe Buddhist monks testify of Jesus Christ, which is what the Holy Ghost does primarily

Let's not close or downvote questions that show little familiarity with Christianity. Everybody has to start learning somewhere.

Buddhist attainment is not from "deep breathing". The Buddha taught something called Anapanasati; meaning breathing from mindfulness. What this means is when the practitioner has the purity & virtue to be able to give up craving, the mind becomes quiet & still & the consciousness of the practitioner starts to drop into the physical body of the practitioner. What then happens is the practitioner becomes acutely aware of the breathing in a way that is united with the spiritual conscience of the practitioner. This is called "touching the Truth with the body". This is the Holy Spirit.

In Trinitarian Christianity (i.e. 98% of Christians) the Holy Spirit is a person of the Trinity, one of the three persons of God. He is the person that the Bible verses you refer to are describing.
It is not possible for a human being to become God the Holy Spirit.
It is possible to say that someone is a person who "has a holy spirit". It's important to note the preposition, the indefinite article and the lack of capital letters. It could be said of anyone who is particularly holy. This would be something entirely different, and isn't often used because of the likelihood of confusion with the Holy Spirit. You can also describe a person as "having the Holy Spirit" meaning that the Holy Spirit person dwells particularly within them.
Note also that in Christianity being a master of deep breathing and meditation does not necessarily make you holy.

.read this. it's a Buddhism website. Can I say the Holy Spirit inside the person wrote this and shared the Gospel and Wisdom ? https://www.greatwesternvehicle.org/christian/JesusMaitreyaBuddha.htm#:~:text=Siddhartha%20Gotama%20called%20the%20future,500%20years%20after%20Siddhartha%20Gotama @DJClayworth

The article is a about Buddhism and it's viewpoint. This site is about Christianity. In Buddhism it may be possible that a holy person can be called "the Holy Spirit" but Holy Spirit would mean something different there from what it means in Christianity. If you wanted to ask about that you should ask on a Buddhism website. Everything I wrote above is from a Christian point of view.

@DJClayworth being a master of deep breathing and meditation --> depends what the person to do with the technique. i.e. some uses their intelligence to help others with higher inner energy/wisdom or share the Gospel or some just destroying each others

@WeiPengYou No, that's not what Christians generally believe. Of course we use our intelligence, but "deep breathing" is not something Christians think is important or beneficial to ministry.
